# Poké-Pelago and the bean effects

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

In Poké-Pelago, you can place Poké-beans in a cart on each island, however, I can't find instructions on what each ones does.

I've found this [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/296672/154636) that dictates that putting beans in the cart for the hot springs will do the following:

> The increase of happiness will be doubled for the Pokémon, while the
>   eggs will hatch faster.

But what do the rest do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isle Abeen: Increases the chances for a wild Pokemon to appear. DOES NOT affect the chances of a Pokemon staying.

Isle Evelup: Decreases the time it takes to complete training.

Isle Aplenny: Decreases the time it takes for berries to grow.

Isle Aphun: Decreases the time it takes for treasure hunt to complete.

For Evelup/Aplenny/Aphun, each bean doubles the speed of the timer for a set amount of time.

For example: 1 Regular Pokebean lasts 10 minutes. This causes the timer to count down twice as fast for 10 minutes, effectively taking 5 minutes instead of 10.

The different tiers of beans last varying lengths of time, with regular Pokebeans lasting the least amount of time and Rainbow beans lasting the longest.

Comment: Do you happen to have any sources for that? If so, I'll gladly accept as the answer :)

Comment: @Draken http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Pelago

Comment: @Draken This is wrong. Beans always cut the time in half. The higher-value beans simply last longer.